# Stripe / Apple-pay Icon presented wrongly/ rejected by apple store

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, appstore-approval, applepay

Apple rejected my app because Stripe pod show inappropriate apple pay icon, which added an extra "apple pay" next to the apple pay icon. (see attached)

Is anyone had the same problem like me and what are your solution?

Is anyone had successfully uploaded an app with apple pay function installed?

[image]

Please See my calling code as below too, many thank!

```
    private func reloadPaymentButtonContent() {

    guard let selectedPaymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption else {
        // Show default image, text, and color
        paymentButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Payment"), for: .normal)
        paymentButton.setTitle("付款", for: .normal)
        paymentButton.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        return
    }

    // Show selected payment method image, label, and darker color
    paymentButton.setImage(selectedPaymentMethod.image, for: .normal)
    paymentButton.setTitle(selectedPaymentMethod.label, for: .normal)
    paymentButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
}

private func reloadBuyButton(){
    if paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption == nil {
        //            buySubscriptionButton.backgroundColor = .loopGrayColor
        //            buySubscriptionButton.setTitle("订阅", for: .normal)
        //            buySubscriptionButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        buySubscriptionButton.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        buySubscriptionButton.isEnabled = true
        //            buySubscriptionButton.backgroundColor = .loopGreenColor
        //            buySubscriptionButton.setTitle("订阅", for: .normal)
        //            buySubscriptionButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: Which method are you calling there? Have you tried `[STPImageLibrary applePayCardImage]`

Comment: Thanks for helping, please see my calling code in the post, I just added it, many thanks!

Comment: well, your line `paymentButton.setTitle(selectedPaymentMethod.label,` is what is showing the text you highlighted in the screenshot(the `label` is "Apple Pay" https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentOption.html#/c:objc(pl)STPPaymentOption(py)label) So either change your code to not show that if you wish(maybe check if you have an instance of `STPApplePayPaymentOption` and don't show the label then), or modify your UI to make it clearer what that label means — i.e. "your currently selected payment method is to pay with Apple Pay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting both in the code. So, either set Image or Label text.